# How can I show ms outlook's notification like popup in java?

Tags: java, swing, popup

How can I show ms outlook's notification like popup in java swing? is it possible? any other alternative for this?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is your notification Popup:

[image: Popup]

Code with example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class NotificationPopup extends JDialog {
  private final LinearGradientPaint lpg;

  public NotificationPopup() {
    setUndecorated(true);
    setSize(300, 100);

    // size of the screen
    final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    // height of the task bar
    final Insets scnMax = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(
        getGraphicsConfiguration());
    final int taskBarSize = scnMax.bottom;

    setLocation(screenSize.width - getWidth(), screenSize.height - taskBarSize
        - getHeight());

    // background paint
    lpg = new LinearGradientPaint(0, 0, 0, getHeight() / 2, new float[] { 0f,
        0.3f, 1f }, new Color[] { new Color(0.8f, 0.8f, 1f),
        new Color(0.7f, 0.7f, 1f), new Color(0.6f, 0.6f, 1f) });

    // blue background panel
    setContentPane(new BackgroundPanel());
  }

  private class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
    public BackgroundPanel() {
      setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
      final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      // background
      g2d.setPaint(lpg);
      g2d.fillRect(1, 1, getWidth() - 2, getHeight() - 2);
      g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

      // border
      g2d.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
    }
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (final Exception e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        final NotificationPopup f = new NotificationPopup();

        final Container c = f.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        final GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weightx = 1.0f;
        constraints.weighty = 1.0f;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        final JLabel l = new JLabel("You have got 2 new Messages.");
        l.setOpaque(false);

        c.add(l, constraints);

        constraints.gridx++;
        constraints.weightx = 0f;
        constraints.weighty = 0f;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

        final JButton b = new JButton(new AbstractAction("x") {

          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            f.dispose();
          }
        });

        b.setOpaque(false);
        b.setMargin(new Insets(1, 4, 1, 4));
        b.setFocusable(false);

        c.add(b, constraints);

        f.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice work. This works fine but it also shows a new window in taskbar for popup and I don't want that.

Comment: @stephen: Using JDialog instead of JFrame solves the problem.

Comment: I know that this question is pretty old, but I wonder that nobody mentioned that Outlook notification window appears slowly and then starts disappearing. So the user isn't forced to click this window away each time it appears.

Comment: Just implement a timer that hides the dialog after a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to take a look at the [System Tray API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/). The [displayIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#displayMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType%29) method should do what you need:

> Displays a popup message near the tray
>   icon. The message will disappear after
>   a time or if the user clicks on it.
>   Clicking on the message may trigger an
>   ActionEvent.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an undecorated JFrame ( frame.setUndecorated(true) ) and calculate the location and size by using Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it takes it for granted that the location of Windows task bar never changes (ie always on the down side of the monitor). It will be more difficult to calculate the correct location when the task bar is somewhere else (eg on the right side).

Comment: @jfpoilpret I did that same way, just with usage of JDialog, are you have there any problem with calculate Location on RightBottom +- CityBus, from 1st of Monitors

Answer (score 0):

You can use JTelegraph for getting a colorful popup. All you have to do is, get its jar file (You also need to get two more jar files along with it) and include it in your build path and start coding.

Detailed and simple instructions are given here - http://tphangout.com/?p=41